# Kivy and Cython game

Tags: python, kivy, cross-platform, cython

I would know if it actually a great deal to make a game in Python using Kivy (OpenGL) and Cython. So is it or not ? If not what should I use for making a cross-platform (computer/mobile) game using Python ?

I haven't even tried because I would know if it was a great idea before making it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is too open.
You need to precise what type of game you want to do. If
you want to do snake or pong, you will be able to do it.
Will it be:

- 2D ? 3D ?
- Turn by turn game ? real time ?
- Multiplayer ?
- Open world ?
- Have you another game to compare to so we can imagine the requirements ?

I would say that if you want to do a multiplayer real time 3D open world game, don't use kivy and cython.

Even if you could make it, would be like using a pistol when you need a RPG and you will suffer.

If you want to do a simple solo player turn by turn 2D game, it's okay.

In all the cases, you will be limited by not using something like Unity or Unreal at one point so you should know in advance how far you want to go in your game creation career.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that's all I needed to know. Have a good day!